# Spring Transaction Propagation - Rollback for specific Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am trying to understand `@Transactional` annotation in spring. I have created following program for testing-

```
import com.transactiondemo.transactiondemo.model.Student;
import com.transactiondemo.transactiondemo.repo.StudentRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepo studentRepo;

    @Transactional
    public Student getStudent(String name){
        Student student = studentRepo.findByName(name);
        student.setSubject("first change done");
        studentRepo.save(student);
        try{
            secondChange(name);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("***********caught");
        }
        return student;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void secondChange(String name) {
        Student student = studentRepo.findByName(name);
        student.setSubject("second change done");
        thirdChange(name);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    private void thirdChange(String name) {
        Student student = studentRepo.findByName(name);
        student.setSubject("third change done");
    }
}
```

```
@ResponseStatus
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student,Integer> {
    Student findByName(String name);
}
```

Here is how I am loading data in Student table at application startup-

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner loadData(StudentRepo studentRepo){
    return args -> {
        Student s=new Student();
        s.setName("ram");
        s.setSubject("initial value");
        studentRepo.save(s);
    };
}
```

I am calling `studentService.getStudent("ram")` from my controller class. How do I make sure that database changes done in `studentService.getStudent()` method are persisted into database even if next called method i.e. `secondChange` from this method throws any exception? **Basically I want changes done in `secondChange()` and `thirdChange()` methods to be rolled-back but not for `getStudent()` method**. I have added `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)` on top of `secondChange()` method but this does not work. When I check in database the value for `SUBJECT` column is equal to `third change done` but I want it to be `first change done` even in case of failures.

Comment: For @Transactional method to have an effect, it needs to be called from outside of the class where you declared it.

Comment: You start your first transaction at getStudent with @Transactional.  You should return from that method and then start a new Transaction from outside where you call second an third change as TomekK states

Comment: Thanks @TomekK, it worked when secondChange() is called from out side of class. One more thing, I was asked this question in interview that there are 3 methods  a(), b(), c(). a() calls b() then b() calls c() i.e. a()->b()->c(). Some exception happens in b() and I needed to figure out a way to rollback transaction in b() and c() but changes in a() should be persisted. Not sure how could I have answered that?

Comment: @AmitChaudhary It's hard to say without knowing full requirements. You could for example surround method calls in try...catch.